# Remove sensitive data stored inside eclipse /.history files from various (unpushed) commits

Tags: eclipse, git

This might sound like duplicate, but my problem is a bit more complicated than  the already answered ones. I regretably did a few very wrong choices and don't know how to get out of the current state of things.

**Note that all of my changes are'nt pushed and are only local**

In my Java webapp, I connect to a database and have the credentials (including password) for that hardcoded in my source code. I wasn't dumb enough to commit the file with the password, I actually commited a file where it said in the comment `//enter your credentials here` and after entering the real password I ran `git update-index --assume-unchanged`. Before pushing my progress I wanted to make sure the password really didn't remain anywhere, so using *gitk* I searched the password in various commits and found out it is visible in (**multiple**) `.../.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.coore.resources/.history/ ...` files.

It's even worse than that though. The */.history* files were only in commits of my *master* branch. I'm now working inside my *devel* branch. Dumb as I was, i tried to remove the bad files using the `git rm --cached` command, **but in my devel branch**. As a result, the password is now visible also in devel's commit history and also I'm unable to checkout into *master*, because every time I try to do that, I get an error saying `The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout: <the name of the file I tried to remove>`.

What do I do to remove all commit history that includes the sensitive data before pushing (I would really like not to push the data, because that will go to a public github repository)

**Again, note that all of this was commited locally and that the remote repo is still empty. If there was a way I could delete all commit history and both branches and commit my progress in a single master commit, I'd be good with even such solution, i feel quite helpless right now.**

Comment: How about: Copy all your source code and resources to a backup folder (use Windows Explorer or `cp`, do not use git tools). Delete your repo, completly purge it from your drive. Init a new repo. `cp` your sources back into the repo. You will then have your first commit with content. All history is gone, all commits and their commit messages are gone.

Comment: Not using the tabula rasa / purge method: You can always make a hard reset on your branch(es). Make sure to copy your sources to a backup folder to not lose your progress. Then make a hard reset (not a soft one). This will wipe all commits. Copy back sources to restore your progress.

Comment: I obviously thought of the purge method too, but I would really make use of a more thorough guide on that. I mean, there might be files that I don't want to copy. Also, the folder still includes many git-related files and the .gitignore, what about stuff like that?

Comment: `org.eclipse.core.resources/.history` is the Eclipse 'Local History'. See the 'General > Workspace > Local History' page in the Preferences.

Comment: The .gitignore file only contains a list of filenames / extensions, that git should ignore. So for example, the .gitignore contains `*.class`, which tells git, to ignore all files ending with `.class`, so compiles java files will not be pushed into the repo. It does not contain any history information or such and it is not bound to a specific path or repository.